# MCC(Matthews Correlation Coefficient) on pyspark

Tags: pyspark

Is there an existing implementation to obtain the MCC(Mathhews Correlation Coefficient) on pyspark?
It is easy to implement one from the confusion matrix, but thought better to re-use if there is one already implemented.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthews_correlation_coefficient

SKLearn API for the same:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.matthews_corrcoef.html

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the data to the name node and use the sklearn's implementation ko MCC there, might not be the best idea though.

```
y_cap = [int(i['prediction']) for i in predictions.select('prediction').collect()]
y = [int(i[condition]) for i in predictions.select(condition).collect()]
confusion = confusion_matrix(y, y_cap)
print(confusion)
tn = np.float64(confusion[0][0])
tp = np.float64(confusion[1][1])
fp = np.float64(confusion[0][1])
fn = np.float64(confusion[1][0])
mcc = (tp * tn - fp * fn) / math.sqrt((tp + fp) * (tp + fn) * (tn + fp) * (tn + fn))
print(mcc)
```